# Ionic 3 - Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}' - while trying to run on device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm getting that error while trying to run an Ionic 3 App on an android device. On the browser is working correctly, but I guess there is an extra layer of validation when running/deploying to a device.

Here is the problematic code:

```
getHomephones(auth_token) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.apiProvider.getRemoteHomephones(auth_token).then(result => {
          this.createOrUpdateHomephones(result.data).then(response => {
            resolve(response);
          });
        });
    });
  }
```

which calls the api provider and gets an array of telephones in return (or at least that's the goal):

```
getRemoteHomephones(auth_token) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + "remote_homephones", {
        headers:{"X-USER-AUTH-TOKEN": auth_token}
      }).subscribe(response => {
        resolve(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm guessing the problem lays on the type declaration on the api side, but I don't seem to find the right way to declare it.

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints that will help you now and in future. I don't have details if this code will be deployed in production but here we go:

- **getRemoteHomephones** should also handle the error case when the HTTP call is failing. (reject the promise, catch the error in the caller)
- Angular loves **Typescript**, so you should also start using it. The solution will not run if there are typescript errors so you will avoid a lot of headaches. (Specifically here you should define an interface that will map on your API response as

  getRemoteHomephones(auth_token) : **PhoneNumber**[])
- Before passing the **result** to **createOrUpdateHomephones** as **result.data**, add an additional validation to make sure the object exists and **data** property is available.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. No, the code isn't intended to be deployed in production - Just learning the ropes, what might explain the lack of validation and error catch you mention. Clearly I need and I am looking forward to getting deeper into Typescript - The solution provided however throws the following error: Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Homephone[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Promise<{}>', but I guess I should be using here an observable instead of a promise, so I might get into that first and then test your solution again.

Comment: Yup, defining an interface for both requested data and phones did the trick. Thanks Andrew for pointing in the right direction.